# AutoEncoder feature layers is unstable

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, autoencoder

I am replicating a linear autoencoder method based on this example here; https://towardsdatascience.com/build-the-right-autoencoder-tune-and-optimize-using-pca-principles-part-ii-24b9cca69bd6

Basically, it is using a one layer linear autoencoder to compare with PCA. X is randomly generated from a normal distribution with dimension 5. The core part of the code looks like this.

```
encoder = Dense(encoding_dim, activation="linear", input_shape=(input_dim,), use_bias = True) 
decoder = Dense(input_dim, activation="linear", use_bias = True)

autoencoder = Sequential()
autoencoder.add(encoder)
autoencoder.add(decoder)

autoencoder.compile(metrics=['accuracy'],
                    loss='mean_squared_error',
                    optimizer='sgd')
autoencoder.summary()

autoencoder.fit(X_train_scaled, X_train_scaled,
                epochs=nb_epoch,
                batch_size=batch_size,
                shuffle=True,
                verbose=0)
```

The feature layer is

```
w_encoder = autoencoder.layers[0].get_weights()[1]
w_decoder = autoencoder.layers[1].get_weights()[1]
```

Every time I fit the model, the output for w_encoder is significantly different

```
Encoder_weights
[[ 0.5596451  -0.7303996 ]
 [-0.08105161  0.43715334]
 [ 0.7571198   0.4995086 ]
 [-0.68543106  0.0496945 ]
 [-0.46657953  0.1231109 ]]
Decoder_weights
[[ 0.5596451  -0.7303996 ]
 [-0.08105161  0.43715334]
 [ 0.7571198   0.4995086 ]
 [-0.68543106  0.0496945 ]
 [-0.46657953  0.1231109 ]]
```

vs

```
Encoder_weights
[[ 0.49870995 -0.594432  ]
 [-0.03552848  0.3591121 ]
 [ 0.6754906   0.42547104]
 [-0.5236658   0.02657888]
 [-0.36780515  0.07721919]]
Decoder_weights
[[ 0.49870995 -0.594432  ]
 [-0.03552848  0.3591121 ]
 [ 0.6754906   0.42547104]
 [-0.5236658   0.02657888]
 [-0.36780515  0.07721919]]
```

Is there any way to make the layer metrics stable between runs?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen for many reasons.

1. The weight of your network is initialized randomly each time, so it's possible to get different results each time you run.
2. Your data loader is random in nature and randomly pulling samples.

If you want reproducibility, try the following,

Use seeds.

```
SEED = 1997
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(SEED)
random.seed(SEED)
np.random.seed(SEED)
tf.random.set_seed(SEED)
```

In the case of running on an Nvidia GPU, you should also use **tensorflow-determinism**

```
pip install tensorflow-determinism
```

and you use it like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
os.environ['TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS'] = '1'
```

For Tensorflow < 2.1, add above and this:

```
from tfdeterminism import patch
patch()
```

Comment: I've already tried using the SEED, and I also add a kernel initializer in each layer. But the output is still different